# Show page numbers in Table

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I'm using [Material UI table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#StickyHeadTable.js) together with [Table Pagination](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/), and I'm trying to display the current page together with the 3 leading pages and the 3 prior pages, instead of showing the count amount.

[image]

I added the following to `TablePagination`

```
<TablePagination labelRowsPerPage='' ...OtherSettings />
```

but I still get the same results. How can I change the text in the image above so that it shows the pages instead of the amount of rows?

Answer (score 3):

As far as Material Design goes, it is designed to show rows (as mentioned in the [Material Design Table Behaviour](https://material.io/components/data-tables/#behavior) on the Pagination section).

But nevertheless, you can try using the `labelDisplayedRows` prop of the `TablePagination` component to modify the text shown for the rows by default and instead show the number of the pages depending on your row data. It would be something like this:

```
<TablePagination
    ...OtherSettings,
    labelDisplayedRows={() => {
      return `${page}-${Math.floor(rows.length / rowsPerPage)}`;
    }}
/>
```

Additionally, a [working sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zn1du) and the relevant prop documentation for the `TablePagination` component: [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/#props).